# Inconsistent xticks rotation for seaborn displot when plotting of subsets of plot on different facets

Tags: python, graph, seaborn

The objective is to have subsets of plot on different facets which is achievable as below.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
sns.displot ( data=iris, x='petal_width', col='species', col_wrap=2, bw_adjust=0.5,
                      kind="kde", rug=True)
plt.xticks ( fontsize=14, rotation=45, ha="right" )
plt.show()
```

which produce

[image]
However, I notice the `x-tick` rendering is not consistent between the top and bottom of the graph,upon setting the `xticks`  to `45`,

edit:
Thanks to [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66468530/6446053), the tick is now properly rotate 45 deg. However, the suggestion still have an issue when setting the xticks label. Specifically, the font size is not consistent.

[image]

The above graph was produced via the code below

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g=sns.displot ( data=iris, x='petal_width', col='species', col_wrap=2, bw_adjust=0.5,
                      kind="kde", rug=True)

g.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
header_name =['1a','1b','1c','1d']
value_tick = [0.5,1,1.5,3]
g.set_xticklabels ( rotation=45 )
plt.xticks ( fontsize=14, ticks=value_tick, labels=header_name, ha="right" )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want all `x-ticks` at 45 rotation ? If yes then just try below code,

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.displot ( data=iris, x='petal_width', col='species', col_wrap=2, bw_adjust=0.5,
                      kind="kde", rug=True);
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
# plt.gca().set_xticks("fontsize"="14", "rotation":"45", "ha":"right" )
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

**Edited:**
You can set `fontsize` in the `set_xticks` function itself. Refer below example:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g=sns.displot ( data=iris, x='petal_width', col='species', col_wrap=2, bw_adjust=0.5,
                      kind="kde", rug=True)

header_name =['1a','1b','1c','1d']
value_tick = [0.5,1,1.5,3]
g.set_xticklabels (fontsize=14, rotation=45 )
plt.xticks(ticks=value_tick, labels=header_name, ha="right" )
```

[image: Output1]

I would really recommend if you want to change the `fontsize` for `sns plot` use its own built-in functionality `sns.set()`. That is way much easier.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set font size using sns
sns.set(font_scale=1.5)  # crazy big

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
g = sns.displot ( data=iris, x='petal_width', col='species', col_wrap=2, bw_adjust=0.5,
                      kind="kde", rug=True)

header_name =['1a','1b','1c','1d']
value_tick = [0.5,1,1.5,3]
g.set_xticklabels (rotation=45 )
plt.xticks ( ticks=value_tick, labels=header_name, ha="right" )
```

[image: Output2]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion jay, can you please check the edited post as other issue still remain

Comment: Hi @jay, appreciate if you can share some thought about the issue post in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66469403/how-to-shift-suptitle-in-seaborn-displot