# How to shift suptitle in Seaborn displot

Tags: python, graph, seaborn

For a plot as below.

[image]

There is an issue whereby the `Main title` is on the same line with the other sub-title.

May I know how shift the `suptitle` further up?

The code to reproduce the above figure is as below

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
fig=plt.figure()
g = sns.displot ( data=iris, x='petal_width', col='species', col_wrap=2, bw_adjust=0.5,
                      kind="kde", rug=True)

header_name =['1a','1b','1c','1d']
value_tick = [0.5,1,1.5,3]
g.set_xticklabels (rotation=45 )
plt.suptitle('Main title')
plt.xticks ( ticks=value_tick, labels=header_name, ha="right" )
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.suptitle(...)` is a [matplotlib figure function](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.suptitle). It has `x` and `y` arguments, with `y=0.98` as the default. You can adjust it to be a bit higher, instead of moving the subplots (in some cases you may not have enough freedom there).

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
fig=plt.figure()
#plt.suptitle("Main Title")
g = sns.displot ( data=iris, x='petal_width', col='species', col_wrap=2, bw_adjust=0.5,                      kind="kde", rug=True) 
header_name =['1a','1b','1c','1d']
value_tick = [0.5,1,1.5,3]
g.set_xticklabels (rotation=45 )
g.fig.suptitle("My super title", y=1.05)
#plt.suptitle('Main title')
plt.xticks ( ticks=value_tick, labels=header_name, ha="right" )
```

[image]